# PHP redirect after search form is send

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I have a small problem with my script. I have a form with min. 2 fields and max. 4 that are added dynamically, so basically I send 2 vars or 3, or 4. I hope I'm clear enough.

The rewrite works ok if I access the url manually.

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/? browse.php?c=$1&j=$2&l=$3&k=$4 [L,QSA]
```

But the problem is that I'm not able to redirect the page to the new URL after the form is submitted.

I use this code in PHP header.php:

```
   $url = "";
   if(isset($_GET["c"])) $url .= $_GET["c"]."/";
   if(isset($_GET["j"])) $url .= $_GET["j"]."/";
   if(isset($_GET["l"])) $url .= $_GET["l"]."/";
   if(isset($_GET["k"])) $url .= $_GET["k"]."/";

   header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
   header('Location: http://www.samedomainhere123.com/'.$url);
```

That's just a sample, the code is bigger but basically does the same thing (if GET var is empty I add a default value for the first 2 vars).

After I enable the redirect function I get in a loop.

What can I do? Is it possible to do this redirect using htaccess?

Thank you.

Comment: is the `http://www.domain.com/` points to the same location as your rewrite rule? if so it is going to hit the same rule and go into infinite loop.

Comment: `http://www.domain.com/` is a real web address owned by a web hosting company, be careful using that in examples

Comment: Pretty sure you can't append a variable in the location header function.  Just use double quotes and put the variable in normally

Comment: it's the same domain, sorry didn't know it was an actual website.

Comment: @elliotanderson: It works ok with append but that's not the problem here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add some php code to check that the request that was made *is actually the one with `browser.php` in it:

```
if(strrpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/browse.php')===true) {
   $url = "";
   if(isset($_GET["c"])) $url .= $_GET["c"]."/";
   if(isset($_GET["j"])) $url .= $_GET["j"]."/";
   if(isset($_GET["l"])) $url .= $_GET["l"]."/";
   if(isset($_GET["k"])) $url .= $_GET["k"]."/";

   header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
   header('Location: http://www.domain.com/'.$url);
}
```

Comment: The condition was set when I called the redirect in php but I got the same loop.

Comment: @doubleb which condition, the check that the REQUEST_URI is actually `/browse.php`? Because if the request was `/c/j/l/k`, and mod_rewrite changes it to `/browse.php?something`, the REQUEST_URI will be `/c/j/l/k`, and **not** `/browse.php`. That variable is essentially what you see in your browser's URL location bar.